# Show HTML document on screen as if it were printed

Tags: printing, html

I have an email in html format. Somehow when it prints it shows a lot of blank space on top before the actual text begins. On the screen it is not like that.

Is there a way to tell my browser to display the file on screen as if it were printed? Or any way to check what style methods apply when printing that don't apply on screen?

Here's some of the code that presents this problem to me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--[if !mso]><!-- --><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!--<![endif]-->
<style>
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    outline: none;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media print {
    * {
        background-color: white !important;
        color: black !important;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 100%; margin: 0;">
<div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #333333; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">Preview Text</div>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" align="center" bgcolor="#0568a6" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;">
<div style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 4px; color: #eeeeee;">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; color: #eeeeee; width: 100%;" bgcolor="#0568A6"><!--[if mso]>
  <table align="center" bgcolor="#0568A6" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<![endif]-->
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="bottom" width="75.5%"> </td>
<td style="float: right;" valign="top" width="24%"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="" style="float: right;" title="" align="right" border="0" width="154" height="33"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--[if mso]>
  </table>
<![endif]--></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;">
<div style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px; color: #111111;">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" bgcolor="#ffffff"><!--[if mso]>
  <table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<![endif]-->
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 18px 0px 4px 0px; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;" valign="top">
<p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 15px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12pt; line-height: 1.25;">Hi Joe,</p>
<p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 15px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12pt; line-height: 1.25;">More text ...</p>

... removed stuff ...

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--[if mso]>
  </table>
<![endif]--></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" align="center" bgcolor="#efefef" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;">
<div style="display: block; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 18px 0px 18px 4px;">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" bgcolor="#efefef"><!--[if mso]>
  <table align="center" bgcolor="#efefef" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<![endif]-->
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 0px 0px 4px 0px; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
<p style="font-size: 9pt; color: #999999; font-family: Verdana, 'Tahoma', sans-serif; line-height: 120%; letter-spacing: 1px;">Footer</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--[if mso]>
  </table>
<![endif]--></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser allows to emulate other media in Dev Tools (more tools -> rendering settings).

[image]